# How To write some text in LogCat when Accessibility Service is connected?

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I want to use Accessibility Service in my android project and I've followed all the steps to implement it correctly (Android manifest file, create MyaccessibilityClass, and also the xml file for the accessibility ). So I don't think I have a problem with the implementation. Now do I need to write any code in the MainActivity.java file about the Accessibility Service ? I've put a simple Log.d("ACTION","connected") in the onServiceConnected method to make sure the service has successfully connected but It's not working when I enable the accessibility service on my device...Please help me..

Manifest File :

```
 <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
    </service>
```

accesscibilityservice.xml

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged|typeWindowStateChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:notificationTimeout="0"
android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.apis.accessibility.TestBackActivity"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds|flagRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows" />
```

MyAccessibilityService.java

```java
package com.scpay.sctest;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public abstract class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {


    public MyAccessibilityService(){
        super();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {

        Log.d("ACTION","Connected");


    }



    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {



    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }




}
```

Comment: @cowboi-peing I have pasted the code now

Comment: The only fault I found is "abstract class MyAccessibilityService" . this class won't be abstrace. and can you paste the log when u enable the accessibility service?